# Фильтр по чекбоксам

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь отсортировать данные с джсона по чекбоксам. Пример данных:

```
 [{
    "id": 111,
    "name": "Standart Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_1.jpg",
    "price": 126,
    "category": "single",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 1,
    "children": 0,
    "bed": "King",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,            
    "reservedFrom": "2020-02-07T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-02-09T23:28:56.782Z"      
},{   
    "id": 112,
    "name": "Standart Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_1.jpg",
    "price": 126,
    "category": "single",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 1,
    "children": 0,
    "bed": "King",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-02-01T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-02-05T23:28:56.782Z"
},  {
    "id": 313,
    "name": "Double Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_3.jpg",
    "price": 320,
    "category": "double",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 2,
    "children": 1,
    "bed": "Twin",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-03-07T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-03-091T23:28:56.782Z"       
},   {
    "id": 314,
    "name": "Double Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_4.jpg",
    "price": 320,
    "category": "double",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 2,
    "children": 0,
    "bed": "Twin",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-03-07T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-03-091T23:28:56.782Z"       
}]
```

после чего фильтрую его по кол-ву людей и датам и загоняю их в новый массив availbleRooms.

```
  availableRooms = data.filter(room => {
            let reservedFromData = new Date(room.reservedFrom);
            let reservedToData = new Date(room.reservedTo);
            let checkinDate2 = new Date(checkinDate);
            let checkoutDate2 = new Date(checkoutDate);
            let wasNotSet = (room.reservedFrom == undefined || room.reservedTo == undefined);
            let isAvaliable =  wasNotSet || ((checkinDate2 <= reservedFromData || checkinDate2 >= reservedToData) && (checkoutDate2 <= reservedFromData || checkoutDate2 >= reservedToData));

            if(!room.adults >= adultsValue && room.children >= childrenValue && isAvaliable)
            return false;

            if(isBreakfastRequired && !room.breakfast)
                return false;

            if(suiteType == true && room.roomType != "suite" ||
              roomType == true  && room.roomType != "room"  ||
              suitesAndRooms == true && room.roomType != "suite" && room.roomType != "room")
                return false;

            if(room.bed == "King" && !kingBed ||
              room.bed == "Queen" && !queenBed ||
              room.bed == "Twin" && !twinBed && 
              (kingBed || queenBed || twinBed))
                return false;
            return true;
              });
```

Такая фильтрация показывает только первый найденный эл, если условие показать и тип кровати кинг и квин, выведет только первый тип.
Как исправить мой фильтр?
И может кто-то подскажет варианты как сделать его изящнее и не таким полотном. Спасибо

Comment: Мне жаль того программиста, который за вами будет поддерживать ваш код. Столько `if` давно не видал.

Comment: я только учусь, потому и прошу совета. Сама понимаю, что мой код не есть хорошо

Comment: для того, чтобы можно было помочь с ошибочным поведением, вам нужно описать все условия для воспроизведения этого поведения, в частности значения `checkinDate`, `checkoutDate`, а также описать ожидаемый и реальный результат

Comment: Ожидаемый результат: вывод данных согласно фильрам. То есть если отмечен только один чекбокс кровати твин, выводить их, если отмечены кровати твин и кинг, выводить оба типа и тд. Реальный результат на сейчас: выводит только первое условие в поиске. то есть если ищем по кроватям кинг и твин, выведет только кинг

Comment: такие вещи (особенно код), пожалуйста, добавляйте в изначальный пост редактированием, а не в коммент (без меншна с помощью @ в комментарии вообще немного смысла, если он обращён к кому-то, кто не является автором комментируемого поста). А так см отредактированный ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пара предварительных советов по организации кода:

Для начала можно `forEach` заменить на `filter`:

```
let availableRooms = data.filter(room => {
    let reservedFromData = new Date(room.reservedFrom);
    let reservedToData = new Date(room.reservedTo);
    let checkinDate2 = new Date(checkinDate);
    let checkoutDate2 = new Date(checkoutDate);
    let wasNotSet = (room.reservedFrom == undefined || room.reservedTo == undefined);
    let isAvaliable =  wasNotSet || ((checkinDate2 <= reservedFromData || checkinDate2 >= reservedToData) && (checkoutDate2 <= reservedFromData || checkoutDate2 >= reservedToData));

    return room.adults >= adultsValue && room.children >= childrenValue && isAvaliable;
});
```

Далее, можно туда же засунуть все остальные условия фильтрации, а не проходить массив целую кучу раз (что заметный проигрыш в производительности, если комнат много):

```
let availableRooms = data.filter(room => ({
    let reservedFromData = new Date(room.reservedFrom);
    let reservedToData = new Date(room.reservedTo);
    let checkinDate2 = new Date(checkinDate);
    let checkoutDate2 = new Date(checkoutDate);
    let wasNotSet = (room.reservedFrom == undefined || room.reservedTo == undefined);
    let isAvaliable =  wasNotSet || ((checkinDate2 <= reservedFromData || checkinDate2 >= reservedToData) && (checkoutDate2 <= reservedFromData || checkoutDate2 >= reservedToData));

    if(!room.adults >= adultsValue && room.children >= childrenValue && isAvaliable)
        return false;

    // обратите внимание, эта строчка плохо читается из-за неудачного названия переменной hasBreakfast - лучше бы она называлась isBreakfastRequired
    if(hasBreakfast && !room.breakfast)
        return false;
    ... // остальные условия в том же порядке
}));
```

Что касается собственно логики фильтрации, тут у вас довольно явная ошибка: вы вначале при `kingBed == true` оставляете в `avaliableRooms` комнаты, у которых тип кровати King, а затем *среди них* в случае `queenBed == true` ищете комнаты с Queen, а это, очевидно, пустое множество. Давайте попробуем аккуратно дописать оставшиеся условия (по большому счёту, вы забыли `else` в тех условиях + в фрагментах типа `room.bed == "King" && room.bed == "Twin"` на самом деле должно быть "или" – иначе условие не выполнится никогда):

```
    if(!room.adults >= adultsValue && room.children >= childrenValue && isAvaliable)
        return false;

    if(hasBreakfast && !room.breakfast)
        return false;

    if(suiteType == true && room.roomType != "suite" ||
       roomType == true  && room.roomType != "room"  ||
       suitesAndRooms == true && room.roomType != "suite" && room.roomType != "room")
        return false;

    if(kingBed == true && room.bed != "King" ||
       queenBed == true && room.bed != "Queen" ||
       twinBed == true && room.bed != "Twin" ||
       kingBed == true && twinBed == true && (room.bed == "King" || room.bed == "Twin") ||
       ...
       )
        return false;
    return true;
}));
```

Но, конечно, это всё равно ужасная реализация, короче будет описать логику "если тип кровати не соответствует фильтру", т.е.:

```
    if(room.bed == "King" && !kingBed ||
       room.bed == "Queen" && !queenBed ||
       room.bed == "Twin" && !twinBed)
       // еще, возможно, понадобится взять всё в скобки и добавить && (kingBed || queenBed || twinBed)
       // если нужна логика "ничего не отмечено = всё выбрано"
        return false;
```

а ещё лучше было бы не хранить данные о каждом типе отдельным флагом (`kingBed`, `queenBed`, `twinBed`), а в объекте с теми же полями (`selectedBedTypes: { King: boolean, Queen: boolean, Twin: boolean }`) и обходить его в `for .. in ..` цикле – иначе добавление нового типа кровати заставит вас менять кучу кода.

Comment: имеете в виду так: if(suiteType && !room.roomType)
                  return false;
                if(roomType && !room.roomType)
                  return false;

Comment: Я применила ваши правки. Первая часть все отлично, а там где пошли условия фильтрации  консоль лог выводит пустой массив, видимо false

Comment: Спасибо большое за вашу помощь, отредактировала у себя и в посте. Но тем не менее по отельности по каждому фильтру ищет, а если их больше одного, то выдает false, в консоли вижу пустой массив

Comment: @dinmep больше одного - типа кровати? Вы смешали два разных решения, 3 строчки начиная с `kingBed == true &&` - лишние

Comment: Вы правы! Еще раз спасибо!  уже ищет по выборке. Возможно я не права, но насколько я вижу с такой логикой если человек ничего не выбрал я хотела бы, чтобы ему выдавались все возможные варианты. А сейчас false и ничего. Поясню: я выбрала даты, кол-во человек и Room&Suites, но не отмачала ни один чекбокс с типом кровати или завтраком и на данный момент при таком раскладе я ничего не увижу в результ поиска, а хотелось бы увидеть все свободные на эти даты номера для такого кол-ва людей вне зависимости от типа кровати и завтрака

Comment: @dinmep внимательнее читайте комменты: "понадобится взять всё в скобки". Условие должно быть `if((room.bed == "King" && !kingBed ||
       room.bed == "Queen" && !queenBed ||
       room.bed == "Twin" && !twinBed) && (kingBed || queenBed || twinBed))`, есть же разница :) (не забудьте зааксептить ответ, если всё получится)

Comment: Yakov, моя благодарность не имеет границ!

Comment: @dinmep вы уже умеете пользоваться отладчиком?

Comment: как раз видео смотрю как дебажить

Comment: @dinmep лучше всё-таки задать отдельный вопрос или в крайнем случае перейти в чат